# Java NotSerializable exception on a LibGdx Array<T>

Tags: java, arrays, libgdx

I'm facing a Java error with my libgdx app. i'm trying to write an object to a file using "ObjectOutputStream"

```
java.io.NotSerializableException
java.io.WriteAbortedException: writing aborted; java.io.NotSerializableException
```

This apparently appears because of the use of an

```
 Array<T> com.badlogic.gdx.utils
```

Class where the error comes from : https://pastebin.com/raw/TF8nV214

GameData class : https://pastebin.com/raw/ESnDFA9n

Is there a way to serialize this type of Array ?
Or is there another way to do this ?

Comment: I don't think that class would be serialisable. Why not use a list or set?

Answer (score 0):

`Array` class of LibGDX is not Serializable, Iterate the array and write out your data.

You can use [Kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo) project to do it automatically. It is [very efficient](https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki), both in speed and small serialized size and it serializes POJOs and most classes without any configuation.

Take a look of some [Kryo serializers](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Saved-game-serialization#libgdx-kryo-serializers) for Array and a few other libgdx classes.